# Can I have a class in Typescript behave as a function?

Tags: function, class, typescript

In Typescript, we can have an interface that represents a function, which looks like so:

```
interface MyFunction {
    (input1: A, input2: B, ...): ReturnType
}
```

Is it possible to do anything like this with a class? I'd like to have a class that behaves as a function, but I can't find any documentation on that.

I've tried the same format within a class, but that doesn't appear to work.

```
class Greeter {
    private greeting: string = 'hello'

    // this doesn't work
    (name: string): string {
        return `${this.greeting}, ${name}`
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your use case for needing the factory function to be a class? I know various libraries do this, as does Array. But with some additional context, we could try to address your larger problem.

Comment: It's not something I can't easily work around, but I was implementing my own variation of a Map and thought it would be neat if I could treat it similar to collections in Scala. Scala classes have a special function, apply(...), which can be implemented to enable an instance to be called like a function. For example, in Scala we can have something like: `val mapThings = ... /*instantiate*/; assert(mapThings('some key') == 'value')

Comment: You can create functions and attach properties to them. They won't be instances of a custom class, but they're objects at least.

Comment: I did something like that with Javascript (for unrelated reasons), but it seems like something that would be more effort than it's worth in Typescript. I'll just use a named function; it seems easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have a class in Typescript behave as a function?

Not at the moment.

There is an issue tracking it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/183

There is also the call constructor proposal in ECMAScript : https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/workingdocs/callconstructor.md